# AngularJS ng-repeat related

Tags: angularjs, loops, angularjs-ng-repeat, e-commerce, magento-1.9

not really sure that I will brief it well or not but it should be easy. I am just stuck with if-condition. Please read the below.

I am facing issue regarding Loop in AngularJS frontend(HTML). I am working on a Magento base eCommerce website and for the Front-end we are using AngularJS.

if you have look at below code, here **model.selected.tier_price** will run 4 times and will print the values like **[1,2,4,6]**,

Each time the **Count** Increase then the below **ng-repeat** will run **4 Times**.

and i have to match **Count** with **tier.price_qty** will return the correct result like here **ng-if="tier.price_qty == model.item.count"**, which is returning accurate/Correct result.

But now my question is when Count is Less than **tier.price_qty** which is **[1,2,4,6]** then how i can handle it ? because it is not just **ng-if="model.item.count < tier.price_qty** Since i need to stay in the Same **Index** as well,

[image]

If you look at the above image then you will see after buying a certain number of products only the price changes. if the user stays below that count then the price will remain same.

here is what I am doing

```
<div ng-repeat="tier in model.selected.tier_price">
   <div ng-if="tier.price_qty == model.item.count"> 
           //print Only When Count Match with Quantity
           {{ model.selected.tier_price[$index].price | price }}
   </div> 

   **HERE IS THE TRICKY PART WHEN COUNT IS THE LESS THAN PRICE-QTY** Like 
  Count == 3 && price-qty == 4

   <div ng-if="model.item.count < tier.price_qty && model.item.count == $index+1">
      Remain the previous Price
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not clear, what you want, post examples of input data and corresponding html outputs for all possible variants.

Comment: you can refer to my another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525010/ng-repeat-with-if-else-conditions-angularjs-front-end-html-part